# Is there a way to filter by isContainedIn instead of Contains

Tags: prisma

I haven't found in the documentation any way to check if an string in the Database is contained inside some variable

ex:

```
prisma.sound.findFirst({
    where: {
        triger : {
            contains: text
         }
    }
})
```

Will generate a request that would look like :

`SELECT * FROM sound WHERE triger LIKE '%' || text || '%'`

Is there a way to generate a request that would look like this :

`SELECT * FROM sound WHERE text LIKE '%' || triger || '%'`

**Edit**:
It doesn't appear that the feature exists yet, i have created an issue here : https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/7589

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible without using a [raw query](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access) that you mentioned above. I would suggest opening a feature request [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md&title=) so that we can look into this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, using a raw query is what i am currently using but it is certainly not the most elegant solution, i will submit a feature request